# <div class="headerFst"> What is this?

Tags: php, html, css, header-files

I have been attempting to remove a repeating header on all of my webpages for customization purposes, but have been unsuccessful finding what is causing this header repeat. 
    I came across this code in the header, and after researching it, I can not find what its purpose is. Could this be my culprit for the repeating patterns? If not, please point me to the right direction.

Thank you for viewing, and helping if possible.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the `html` or `css` you have provided. So can you please provide a little more of your code or explain a little more to help us debug your problem.

Comment: You are asking a very general question. If you are using an advanced text editor like Sublime Text, try searching the whole project folder for instances of it. Maybe there's also a JavaScript code that clones that section.

Comment: @Mcometa. Are you saying that is too of an easy question? I am not sure I am understanding your comment. It is perplexing for me, because I am a newbie. Thank you for your suggestion, but I have searched my files already using grep, and there was nothing but the two files I had pasted originally in my post, from the look.css and header.ctp file. Strangely that is not in my post anymore.

Answer (score 0):

look this should be comment but there is nothing wrong in the code, if your header is including in every page, than you should look for the php file, like index.php, and look for the include(), function, and check in which include function you are including this file like this

`include('file_name_for_this_header_file');`

lets say the name of the file is header, than include function should look like this `include('header');`

commment out it this line like this

`// include('header');` and check if any thing changes,

or you can check the include_once as well same way

and remember its just a rough guess from my side.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have used grep to display all of these include functions, and only came up with one that was relevant, but it was in my forum files, and I don't think that was it.

Comment: Thank you for the helpful article link! The articel gave me some ideas where and what to look for. So, if I understand correctly, "Using blocks for script and CSS files" is what may be causing the repeating header on my CakePHP site? I found a ctp file I normally don't go I think may be the code that I have been looking for, but I am not sure. I will attach a snip of the code in the next comment since it is too long for this one...

Comment: `code`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://example.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3example.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?>
</title>
 <?php echo $html->meta( 'icon' ) ?>
 
 
 <?php echo $html->css('style');?>
 
 <?php echo $html->css('frontend/development-bundle/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css');?>
 
 <?php echo $html->css('CalendarControl');?> `code`

Comment: The above code did not paste into here very well. I hope you can understand it enough to tell me if I am in the right area, and by the way your English is fine! :)